# OpenGL: Able to see inside of an object despite the fact that transparency is set to 1.0

Tags: opengl, transparency

I am trying to check transparency and how it works.

I have created a solidsphere and a solidcube in it.
I have enabled

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);  
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The transparency works as expected using color4f.
The problem is that when I am setting the transparency of the sphere to 1.0, the cube still appears.

I am also using these:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
glClearDepth(1); 
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);  
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
```

How can I make the cube visible only when the transparency of the sphere is != 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you've set `glFrontFace(GL_CW);` ?  The default is `GL_CCW`, so you'll be culling front faces, and rendering back faces. With the front of the sphere missing, you'll see inside it.

To elaborate:

When rendering translucent objects using a normal (src_alpha , 1-src_alpha) blend, the translucent surfaces need to be rendered in depth order, back to front.

If you render only the back-surfaces of an object, it may (if it's more or less symmetrical) appear normal, but it is in fact inside-out, and thus cannot occlude objects correctly which are actually inside it.

So for this to work, it is important both that the front-surfaces are not culled, and that the opaque or more distant objects are rendered first.

If you want both front and back of the sphere to render translucently, and correctly, you would need to render the back before the front. This could be done with polygon sorting, but for a convex object it would suffice to render it twice, with the backface culling inverted - so render back faces first, and then the front faces, in two seperate passes.

Comment: I have added for some other testing. Just removed it, but with the sphere's alpha set to 0.5 I cannot still see the cube inside it.

Comment: Are you rendering the cube first?

Comment: If you mean if it's first on the code, then yes it is. (sorry for the delayed reply)